# Get latest modification date of sub-folders of each folder in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I need to get the top 3 files having the latest date of modification of a sub-folders of each folder of a main folder.

The script should go through each of every sub folder of the specified main-folder and list the files having the latest date of each sub folder of the main-folder.

This script gets the latest modification date of a folder taking into consideration all the sub-folders

```
find /path/ -exec stat \{} --printf="%n %y\n" \; | sort -n -r | head -3
```

But I need to iteration through sub-folders of the main-folder to get a list of folders and filenames having the earliest date of modification of each folder.

```
for folder in MAINFOLDER
do
find ***folder*** exec stat \{} --printf="%n %y\n" \; | sort -n -r | head -1
loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
for folder in MAINFOLDER/*
do
   find "$folder" -exec stat \{} --printf="%n %y\n" \; | sort -n -r | head -3
done
```

Comment: thats exactly what I wanted! A small correction in the script, it should have been:
   _find "$folder" -exec stat \{} --printf="%n %y\n" \; | sort -n -r | head -3_

Comment: @magnum ah! was missing `-` in `exec`. actually copied from your question only! It seems you're new to SO. If any answer worked for you, consider accepting it by clicking on hollow green tick mark besides answer.